# How can I attach event handler for a collection view in Backbone.js when one of the models is changed?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, events, event-handling, backbone.js

I have a view that renders a tasks list:

```
ProjectManager.Views.TasksIndex = Support.CompositeView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.collection.bind("add", this.render);
  },

  render: function () {
    this.renderTemplate();
    this.renderTasks();
    ...
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    $(this.el).html(JST['tasks/index']({ tasks: this.collection }));
  },

  renderTasks: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.collection.each(function(task) {

      // only display draft tasks
      if (task.get('status') === "draft") {
        var taskItem = new ProjectManager.Views.TaskItem({ model: task });
        self.renderChild(taskItem);
        self.$('#tasks-list').append(taskItem.el);
      }
    });
  }
  ....
});
```

I render a view for each task that is in the collection. I would like to be able to delete a task.
I got to the point when after user clicks a delete button for a task I set a status attribute on task model to "deleted". Now somehow I need to bind an event handler in my TasksIndex view to re-render the collection.
I tried

```
this.collection.bind("change", this.render);
```

but it didn't work.
How can I propagate event that happened on the model in the child view to the parent view?

Comment: Where are you placing this.collection.bind("change", this.render);? A model's change event should propagate to its owning collection.

Comment: I placed it in the initialize. Yeah I was surprised that it wouldn't propagate to the collection. But after I tried again it worked (probably something else was wrong in the model's view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.collection.bind('change', this.render)` should call the `render` method when the model status is changed.

Can you add a `console.log('render called');` line to your render method to see if the it's being called when the model status is changed.

I'm thinking the render method is being called but there's some logic elsewhere that is not correctly displaying the tasks.

Comment: Yes it did work this time when I tried again (for some reasons render is even called twice every time I delete a task). I did mess around with my code trying to get it work so I might have unintentionally corrected some of the logic elsewhere. Thank you!